# Unable to select all elements using jQuery class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, tags

Here iam having a table data in which 3 input items which are having a common class **submit3**.Whenever i want to select the 3 buttons using jQuery and want to change the value and name attributes of these elements to some other text.

Here iam including the code snippet of the data

```
<td colspan=2>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit3" onclick="return checknull()" tabindex="1">

    <input type="button" value="Reset" class="submit3" onclick="call_reset()" tabindex="1">

    <input type="button" value="Forgot Password ?" class="submit3" onclick="call_fgpwd()" tabindex="1">

</td>
```

But when iam selecting with jquery using the class selector $('.submit3') it only returning the first input submit button and it is ignoring the remaining 2.

Here original javascript is here

```
document.getElementsByClassName("submit3")[0].value = "something";
document.getElementsByClassName("submit3")[1].name = "something";
document.getElementsByClassName("submit3")[2].name = "something";
document.getElementsByClassName("submit3")[2].value = "something";
```

Now i tried converting it into jquery as

```
$('.submit3')[0].val("Something New")
```

Which resulted in error  `Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].val is not a function`

Also in the console of chrome browser(Latest Version),when i run $('submit3')
the output is 
`<input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit3" onclick="return checknull()" tabindex="1">`
[image]

Comment: `$('.submit3')[0]` refers to the element, not to a jQuery object.

Answer (score 4):

In your code `$('.submit3')[0]` returns the dom object, you can't use jQuery **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** method with it. You can set `value` property to update the value.

```
$('.submit3')[0].value = "Something New"
```

or use **[`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq)** method to get jQuery object using index

```
$('.submit3').eq(0).val("Something New")
// or $('.submit3:eq(0)').val("Something New")
```

Comment: ```$('.submit3').eq(1).name("Reset")``` will this work??

Comment: @SaiKiranUppu :  there is no methode like `name()`..... use `attr()`.... `$('.submit3').eq(1).attr('name',"Reset")`

Answer (score 2):

When you convert a jQuery collection `$('.submit3')` to `$('.submit3')[0]` - raw DOM element `[HTMLElement]`, the jQuery properties don't work. Use plain JS properties.

```
$( ".foo" )[ 0 ] // is equivalent to document.getElementsByClassName( "foo" )[0]
```

Use

```
$('.submit3')[0].value = ...
```

or alternatively

```
$('.submit3').get(0).value = ..
```